# Drag content between browser windows

Tags: javascript, web-applications

This is a long-shot, and I'm pretty sure it's not possible, but I thought I'd ask just in case someone knows some voodoo that I'm not privy to.

Is it possible at all, under any circumstances, with any browser, even if a plugin of some sort is necessary, to drag an element from one browser window to another?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. I can drag an image from a page in firefox into chrome without a problem.

Comment: @j08691, That has more to do with dragging files around, if I understand correctly.  What he wants to do is a bit different.

Comment: @Brad - seems a bit ambiguous, no?

Comment: I want to drag *elements* of a page, i.e. HTML elements, like a div or something.  Not text or images or something that could be put in the clipboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dragging between browser windows works by default as long as you use the native JS drag APIs.
(Tested with Firefox 106.0.5 and Chrome 107.0.5304.107)

Use [`event.dataTransfer.setData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/setData) in your `dragstart` event handler to set it and [`event.dataTransfer.getData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/getData) in your `drop` event handler to retrieve it.

Two caveats:

- The data must be a string. For your use case of dragging HTML elements, this is not a problem, as they're already serialized through their `outerHTML` property.
- It does not work cross browser, only between different windows of the same browser.

Comment: awesome!  I can't remember what I was trying to accomplish, specifically, 10 years ago, but I'm glad browsers can finally do this 

Comment: I did not expect a reaction from you after 10 years, wow.  I mainly answered for other people coming from search engines.
But now that you're here already, will you please provide me with some juicy internet points by marking it as the accepted answer, dear stranger? 

Comment: StackOverflow ***very unfortunately*** won't let me revoke those juicy internet points if I test it later and discover it doesn't work, so I've stopped assuming answers are 100% accurate before I've tested them... I just tested on the page you linked to, and it did not work across windows for me in Chrome 104, but it did work in Firefox 104, so juicy internet points are coming your way!  

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit out there, but here's a nasty hack of a setup that might work for you with some tweaking.

Flash has a class called `LocalConnection` that uses IPC to communicate with other Flash instances.  While this is often used between Flash movies on the same page, it does work between Flash movies in other browser windows, and even other browsers completely.  For instance, you could send messages from a Flash movie on a page in Chrome to a Flash movie on a page in Internet Explorer.

Now, this communication channel should be most of what you need.  The flow should be something liket his:

1. Detect a start drag on page A
2. Detect the mouse leaving page A
3. Broadcast a message that events 1/2 have happened, along with any needed data describing the object being dragged.
4. Detect that broadcast on page B, and hang on to it for a bit.
5. Detect the mouse entering page B
6. Detect a mouse-up on page B
7. Act on the data that was previously broadcast.

Not pretty, and error-prone, but depending on how badly you need this, might work.

Answer (score 2):

Because of the way JavaScript works it's difficult to move data from one window to another. Even if you're using frames (on the same domain).

If you make a `DOMElement` in one frame you're not allowed to add it to the DOM of another frame because they don't share the same ancestry. Similarly `instanceof` checks will fail if you send objects between frames and so on.

You could however mock it but this requires the two windows to be very much in synch with each other (via the server? lag?). If you end the drag event on the window once you reach the edge, have it send a signal to the server that starts a drag-start event on the other window with the appropriate data etc you *could* make it work.

Comment: So, if I understand: as soon as your mouse leaves the first window without a mouseup, you send AJAX to the server, and (e.g. through Comet) tells the second window to expect the drag.  If the second window receives a mouseover with mouse button still down (I'm not sure if you can detect that it's *still* down! so you might need to assume that) it interpret it as a drag.  Also, the communication to the server tells the server what element is being dragged, so the second window can draw it?

Comment: For usability, because of the possible lag, I think it would be good to post a notice on the first window explaining that the system is preparing to receive a drag on another window.  The second window, when ready, should show some visual indicator that it's ready to receive the drag.  Then the user can complete it successfully.

Comment: Yes .. usability will be hard here. There is so much that could go wrong.